optocoupler circuit with varing resistor
I've tried to analyze the following circuit

with ltspice.
I tried to explain why greater the Rx is, the output voltage peak-to-peak value increases but with a limitation and it will finally behave the opposite.

I try to explain it by assuming in some condition BJT(Q1) will enter saturation mode, but I fail to verify it.
What I've known is:
When Rx increases, Vbe of Q1 will decrease, so Ic of Q1 decreases, thus V(in) increases because V(in) equals Vcc-Ir6*Ic and then amplified by differentiator. But I still can not figure out why output will decrease eventually.

What is the purpose of varying Rx in the simulation?  That's an odd resistor to vary.

The purose is to vary the voltage gain, but there is a limit. This limit is what I am wondering.

I think the 4.7u caps effects the result. At 1kHz they should be 100u at least, otherwise their voltage fluctuates in period instead of holding constant value.

Suppose Rx = \$\infty \$. With a base-emitter voltage of only 250mVAC pk Q1 would be entirely off and there would be no output at all. So you know it has to decrease at some point.
I suggest plotting transient voltages (eg. vs time) for different Rx values and looking at the collector voltage waveform (for starters) to see what exactly is going on. It's better to save this kind of plot for when you have a very good idea of what nonlinearities are involved- you're hiding the details.

Thx for your suggestion. I plot it and the transient waveform shrinks in the time interval of positive half period and some kind of distortion happend in the negative half. How to explain it?

As you increase Rx the negative part will get smaller and disappear, then the positive part because the bias is not enough to make the transistor operate as an amplifier.
